# Digital implementation of type I compensation network

Tags: filter-design, feedback

I'm looking for advice or references on how to implement a "type I" compensation network of digitally.  An analog example is shown in the following diagram:

[image]

I am familiar with the basics of digital signal processing, and have read about digital integrators.  Would it be possible to use something like a first order IIR digital integrator, and just flip the sign of the output depending upon whether the input is above or below VREF? The goal is to drive a PWM output of a microprocessor, so there may be a better way to do this in the digital domain than attempting to copy the analog implementation.  Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The integrator is unstable, so it will probably just blow up. There's such a thing as a leaky integrator that does an OK job of getting pretty close. Have a look at the algorithm listed [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter.html#f83-1015962) on how you would go about implementing it using code. The math is pretty straightforward.

The differentiator uses b1=1, b2=-1. The integrator is just the inverse, but what you'll find is you need to modify (decrease) the filter coefficient by a subtle amount to make it 'leak'. For the integrator use something like a1=1, a2=-0.99. The closer a2 gets to 1.0 the greater the risk you run on it going unstable. Decreasing a2 to something like -0.95 will result in something that looks less and less like an integrator. Play around with it.

Answer (score 0):

The leaky integrator suitable for part of your solution.  See these links for more information.

[Mathematical Proof of Complementary Filter？](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/10609/mathematical-proof-of-complementary-filter/10611#10611)

[How to determine the parameter of a Complementary Filter?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/10220/how-to-determine-the-parameter-of-a-complementary-filter/10613#10613)